# Smooth scroll internal link won't work

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have this html:

```
<html>
  <head>
     <title>Welcome</title>
  </head>

  <body>

    <form id = "form_createaccount_button" action="#createchooserblink">
        <input type="submit" value="go to article" />
    </form>

    <br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
    <br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>

    <a name = "createchooserblink">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi molestie leo ornare vestibulum accumsan. Etiam dignissim leo cursus eleifend dapibus. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Integer et condimentum nunc. Vivamus libero ante, malesuada sed neque vitae, tristique aliquet mi. Vestibulum imperdiet blandit condimentum. Vestibulum sit amet iaculis felis. Sed quis condimentum est, at pellentesque elit. Curabitur rhoncus erat ut magna dictum, in pretium lectus accumsan. Praesent vel libero justo.
    </a>

  <script>
    $(function() {
      $('a[href*="#"]:not([href="#"])').click(function() {
      if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
      var target = $(this.hash);
      target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
      if (target.length) {
        $('html, body').animate({
          scrollTop: target.offset().top
        }, 1000);
        return false;
      }
    }
  });
  });
</script>

  </body>
</html>
```

When clicking the `go to article link`, it moves me to the bottom article text which worked perfectly. The only thing that is not working is the javascript which was suppose to "semi-animate" the page to scroll to the said link.

Did I wrote something wrong?

Comment: No errors in console?

Comment: try adding `minus` value for offset till your animation reaches the desired element below. You add for example `target.offset().top -100` to offet 100 from top.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't work because of your selector.

```
$('a[href*="#"]:not([href="#"])')
```

There is no "a" tag in your DOM tree. Change it to `$('#form_createaccount_button input')`

**UPDATE**

I corrected whole your HTML sample. You may correct your document like this.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>

  <body>

    <form id = "form_createaccount_button" action="#createchooserblink">
        <input type="submit" value="go to article" />
    </form>

    <br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
    <br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>

    <a name = "createchooserblink">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi molestie leo ornare vestibulum accumsan. Etiam dignissim leo cursus eleifend dapibus. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Integer et condimentum nunc. Vivamus libero ante, malesuada sed neque vitae, tristique aliquet mi. Vestibulum imperdiet blandit condimentum. Vestibulum sit amet iaculis felis. Sed quis condimentum est, at pellentesque elit. Curabitur rhoncus erat ut magna dictum, in pretium lectus accumsan. Praesent vel libero justo.
    </a>

    <script>
      $(function() {
          $('input').click(function(e) {
          e.preventDefault();
          var hash = $(this).parent('form').attr('action');
          var target = $(hash);
          target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + hash.slice(1) +']');
          if (target.length) {
            $('html, body').animate({
              scrollTop: target.offset().top
            }, 1000);
          }

          setTimeout(function(){window.location.href = window.location.href + hash}, 1000);
      });
      });
    </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: @Dranreb I've updated my answer and modified your sample HTML code.

Comment: Man I copy-pasted your code to my page, it still won't scroll down. Instead it would just view the bottom instantly... I'm sorry man.. I really don't know what's happening...

Comment: @Dranreb I'm sorry, I thought you will notice that jQuery library should be added. I updated my answer again this time it should work ;)

Comment: @Dranreb i forgot to say that if you don't want hash like "#createchooserblink" to be added to the URL of the page just remove "setTimeout(..." line at the bottom of the script. I added it because I thought you might need the hash to be there :)

Comment: Thanks so much again bro! Haha! I was really wondering a while ago if you could somehow remove the hashtags on the header. It kinda looks suspicious to them haha! Thanks!